# Having trouble with reading text files

Tags: java, file, text

I seem to be having a problem with this code. The purpose is to find out the average number of tries it takes to roll a 1 on a 5 sided die. I think I have the math right; I just can't get the `while` loop that reads the text file to work.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class BottleCapPrize
{
   public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
   {
      Random randy = new Random();

      PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(new File("boost.txt"));
      Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File("boost.txt"));

      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

      int trials;
      int tries = 6;
      int winCap = 6;
      int token = 0;
      double average;
      int total = 0;

      System.out.print("Please enter the number of trials: ");
      trials = in.nextInt();

      for (int loop = 1; loop <= trials; loop++)    
      {
          winCap = 6;
          tries = 0;
          while (winCap != 0)
          {
              tries++;
              winCap = randy.nextInt(5);
          }
          outFile.println(tries); 
          System.out.println(tries);
      }

      while (inFile.hasNext())
      {
          token = inFile.nextInt();
          total = total + token;
      }

      average = (double)total/(double)trials;
      System.out.println("Average : " + average);

      outFile.close();
      inFile.close();
      in.close();
   }
}
```

Comment: What is your current output and what is the contents of your text file?

Comment: Why are you reading and writing with the same file?

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean

```
while (inFile.hasNextLine())
```

or

```
while (inFile.hasNextInt())
```

Hope helps!

Answer (score 0):

You don't close your output file. As your output file is also your input file, you won't be able to read the input unless you close the output first.

Move the outFile.close() before the `while (inFile.hasNext())`, and don't open your inFile before you closed your outFile:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class BottleCapPrize
{
   public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
   {
      Random randy = new Random();

      PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(new File("boost.txt"));

      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

      int trials;
      int tries = 6;
      int winCap = 6;
      int token = 0;
      double average;
      int total = 0;

      System.out.print("Please enter the number of trials: ");
      trials = in.nextInt();

      for (int loop = 1; loop <= trials; loop++)    
      {
          winCap = 6;
          tries = 0;
          while (winCap != 0)
          {
              tries++;
              winCap = randy.nextInt(5);
          }
          outFile.println(tries); 
          System.out.println(tries);
      }

      outFile.close();
      Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File("boost.txt"));

      while (inFile.hasNext())
      {
          token = inFile.nextInt();
          total = total + token;
      }

      average = (double)total/(double)trials;
      System.out.println("Average : " + average);

      inFile.close();
      in.close();
   }
}
```